# Rake tasks cannot find rvm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ssh, rake

I have an ubuntu server setup to run a Rails 4 app with RVM.  When I ssh into the server and run ruby -v it displays 
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

which is the correct ruby version I set through rvm.  However when I try to run a rake task using net/ssh it doesn't see rvm and instead outputs
ruby 1.9.3 
which was the default system ruby.  I am using the same ssh user for both attempts.

How do I get a rake task to recognize rvm?   My script is as follows

```
require 'net/ssh'

desc "Deploy site to production"

task :deploy => :environment do

  commands = [
    "ruby -v"
  ]

  Net::SSH.start('mysite.com', 'deployuser') do |ssh|
    commands.each { |c| puts ssh.exec!(c) }
    ssh.loop
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your bash profile is not being loaded when using Net::SSH. The user's profile sets the RVM version.

I've seen it when trying to run cron jobs. According to https://rvm.io/deployment/cron you can create a wrapper script that sets up the ruby version / gems environment you need. Something like:

```
# find the ruby environment (one time only)
rvm env --path -- ruby-version[@gemset-name]

# set the source returned, e.g.
source /usr/local/rvm/environments/ruby-2.1.1@projectX
ruby -v
```

You may need to adapt appropriately based on your environment